# Image from Picturebox transfers to another form when clicked vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, label, picturebox

I need help transferring image to another picturebox when clicked. I have a Form1 that contains 6 images. IE: When the first image is clicked Form2 will load with a picturebox containing the first image clicked from Form1.

Answer (score 0):

in form1 try this simple code

```
    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        Form2.PictureBox1.Image = Me.PictureBox1.Image 'from form1 Image
        Form2.Show()
   End Sub
```